# EMR Hadoop-streaming job fails while looking for container_tokens

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-yarn, emr

Attempt to run EMR Streaming job frequently fails with:

```
2014-10-15 18:36:36,560 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnUncaughtExceptionHandler: Thread Thread[main,5,main] threw an Exception.
java.io.IOException: Exception reading /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1413396780703_0003/container_1413396780703_0003_01_000218/container_tokens
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:744)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:605)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:98)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1413396780703_0003/container_1413396780703_0003_01_000218/container_tokens (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:172)
    ... 4 more
```

The failure is indeterminate, but too frequent on large clusters. This is how I launch the cluster:

```
elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --instance-group master --instance-type m1.large \
--instance-count 1 \
--instance-group core --instance-type r3.xlarge \
--instance-count 200 --hadoop-version "2.4.0" \
--ami-version "3.2.1" --enable-debugging --json ./emr_config \
--bootstrap-action 's3://path/to/bootstrap.sh' --bootstrap-name Bootstrap
```

And this is the step configuration (emr_config):

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Step Name",
    "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
    "HadoopJarStep": {
      "Jar": "/home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar",
      "Args": [
         "-files", "s3://path/to/mapper.py",
         "-input",     "s3://path/to/input/",
         "-output",    "s3://path/to/output/",
         "-mapper",    "mapper.py",
         "-reducer",   "/bin/cat",
         "-jobconf",   "mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx22528m",
         "-jobconf",   "mapreduce.map.memory.mb=23424",
         "-jobconf",   "mapreduce.task.timeout=24000000",
         "-jobconf",   "mapreduce.job.maps=200",
         "-jobconf",   "mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=1",
         "-jobconf",   "mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Anyone know the source of problem, or a workaround?

Comment: You should look at the nodemanager log on the node that caused the failure. Correlate the timestamps and look for tokens related entries (the token creation is logged at info level)

Comment: @RemusRusanu - what should I look for with regards to tokens? There are some token creation entries, but no errors AFAICT. Also, I'm not sure its any specific node - had this failure across different clusters.

Comment: Did you find a cause of/solution to this?

Comment: @ThomasLarssonKron - No, I ended up using a different cluster size, which didn't exhibit the problem.